# CEFsharp mouse click doesnt work inside browser

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

My requirement is to Show a Win Form without a border. I want to Allow Dragging of the control without border. So i implemented ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor from this https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor/-/php-chromewidgetmessageinterceptor-class-examples.html. But after implementing this it can be dragged. The browser has X button .When I click it doesn't work .When I click on webpage elements it should respond automatically. None of the mouse click events work inside browser. Also if I put the border on the Form .The mouse click inside the browser works perfectly fine. There is no issue with JS or HTML files.
I tried simple google.com but doesn't work, if I click on search button.
Below is the code.

---

```
   public class Form1{
    private ChromiumWebBrowser mBrowserView; 
    private int mMinWidth = 250;
    private int mMinHeight = 350;
    private bool formClosed;
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    private bool isDragging;
    ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor chromeWidgetMessageInterceptor;
    private IntPtr browserHandle;
    private ILog mLog;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">The h WND.</param>
    /// <param name="Msg">The MSG.</param>
    /// <param name="wParam">The w parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">The l parameter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    /// <summary>
    /// Releases the capture.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    /// <summary>
    /// Posts the message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">The h WND.</param>
    /// <param name="Msg">The MSG.</param>
    /// <param name="wParam">The w parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">The l parameter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="PopUpControl"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the pop up control.
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
    public void DisplayBrowser()
    {
         
        if (mBrowserView == null)
        {
            mBrowserView = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
            mBrowserView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(mBrowserView);
            mBrowserView.HandleCreated += MBrowserView_HandleCreated;
            mBrowserView.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += MBrowserView_IsBrowserInitializedChanged; ;
            mBrowserView.MouseDown += MBrowserView_MouseDown; ;
            mBrowserView.MouseUp += MBrowserView_MouseUp;
            mBrowserView.MouseMove += MBrowserView_MouseMove;
        }
        else
        {
            mBrowserView.Load(url);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the MouseMove event of the MBrowserView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="MouseEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void MBrowserView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragging)
            this.Location = Cursor.Position;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the MouseUp event of the MBrowserView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="MouseEventArgs" /> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void MBrowserView_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = false;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the MouseDown event of the MBrowserView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="MouseEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void MBrowserView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the HandleCreated event of the MBrowserView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void MBrowserView_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browserHandle = ((ChromiumWebBrowser)mBrowserView).Handle;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the IsBrowserInitializedChanged event of the MBrowserView control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private void MBrowserView_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mBrowserView.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            SetupMessageInterceptor();
            mBrowserView.ShowDevTools();
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Setups the message interceptor.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupMessageInterceptor()
    {
        if (chromeWidgetMessageInterceptor != null)
        {
            chromeWidgetMessageInterceptor.ReleaseHandle();
            chromeWidgetMessageInterceptor = null;
        }

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    IntPtr chromeWidgetHostHandle;
                    if (ChromeWidgetHandleFinder.TryFindHandle(browserHandle, out chromeWidgetHostHandle))
                    {
                        chromeWidgetMessageInterceptor = new ChromeWidgetMessageInterceptor((Control)mBrowserView, chromeWidgetHostHandle, message =>
                        {
                            const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;
                            const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
                            const int WM_DESTROY = 0x0002;
                            const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
                            const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
                            // Render process switch happened, need to find the new handle
                            if (message.Msg == WM_DESTROY)
                            {
                                SetupMessageInterceptor();
                                return;
                            }

                            if (message.Msg == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE)
                            {
                                // The default processing of WM_MOUSEACTIVATE results in MA_NOACTIVATE,
                                // and the subsequent mouse click is eaten by Chrome.
                                // This means any .NET ToolStrip or ContextMenuStrip does not get closed.
                                // By posting a WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message to a harmless co-ordinate of the
                                // top-level window, we rely on the ToolStripManager's message handling
                                // to close any open dropdowns:
                                // http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripManager.cs,1249
                                var topLevelWindowHandle = message.WParam;
                                PostMessage(topLevelWindowHandle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                            }
                            //Forward mouse button down message to browser control
                            else
                            {
                                PostMessage(browserHandle, (uint)message.Msg, message.WParam, message.LParam);
                                mLog.Error("Message when clicked  WM_LBUTTONDOWN");
                            }


                            // The ChromiumWebBrowserControl does not fire MouseEnter/Move/Leave events, because Chromium handles these.
                            // However we can hook into Chromium's messaging window to receive the events.
                            //
                            const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
                            const int WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3;

                            switch (message.Msg)
                            {
                                case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                                    mLog.Error("Message when clicked Mouse move WM_MOUSEMOVE");
                                    break;
                                case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
                                    mLog.Error("Message when clicked Mouse WM_MOUSELEAVE");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    mLog.Error("Message when clicked not falling in any case"+message.Msg.ToString());
                                    break;

                            }
                        });

                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Chrome hasn't yet set up its message-loop window.
                        await Task.Delay(10);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Errors are likely to occur if browser is disposed, and no good way to check from another thread
            }
        });
    }
```

### }

Comment: Try the example at https://github.com/qwqcode/CefSharpDraggableRegion

Comment: Version 90 also includes classes to simplify hooking the chromium hwnd see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/90.6.x/html/N_CefSharp_WinForms_Experimental.htm see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/90/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L281 for an example

Comment: Hi I have tried the above solutions . In the code i have used the Message interceptor. The problem is it i m not able to achieve the Drag event and Click event in the chrome browser. Simple checkbox click doesnt work in the page if i enable drag. Can you please help.

Comment: Did you download and test the example at https://github.com/qwqcode/CefSharpDraggableRegion

Comment: You can use JavaScript to capture mouse events which is generally quite a bit easier see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent You can capture mouse events for specific element(s).